French student long stay visa appeal
I had applied for a French student  long stay visa last year to pursue Msc in Aerospace Engineering, my visa was refused and the refusal letter stated " you pose a threat to public health/ safety/ security". I followed the procedure to appeal and appealed through CRRV first but there wasn't any response for two months, appealed in the Nantes administrative court in February 2024, and still waiting for their response.
I would like to know if anyone has faced French student visa refusals on the grounds of security reasons and how long does it usually take for the Nantes Court to respond?
